# How to remove opacity in bar chart Highchart in case of scroll

Tags: angular, highcharts

all in case of the large data set. I am using scroll in bar chart highcharts lib but when users scroll up or down data are getting hidden inside scroll. How can we remove the opacity while using the scroll in the bar chart highchart.

[image]

Comment: From the image, it looks like the opacity is coming from the legend.  The sample implementation doesn't have the opacity https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/yaxis/inverted-bar-scrollbar/.   Do you have a working fiddle you can share?

Comment: Hi @Rohit Mehrotra, As Barbara noticed, the problem doesn't occur in a chart with basic settings. Please share your configuration, you can update this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ajsdfg1b/

Answer (score -1):

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // for window scroll events
onScroll(event) {
  //do something
}
```

OR

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)"></div>
```

Then edit the element's style or add a css class, for example:

```
   if (window.scrollY === 33) {
    document.querySelector(".main_container.ng-scope").style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Hope this is useful for you

Comment: Get the scroll event with HostLIstener or with onScroll method. In "main_container" you put the opacity bar class.